# unix date util + bash get a "last monday" starting from a given date

Tags: bash, date, unix

I see that unix date util provides a way to create a date from a string with specified format.
And it can also create a date using such strings as "last monday" or X days ago.
Is it possible to get a  last monday  for any given date using just date util and bash.
Something akin

> ```
> date -d "$(date -d '-24 day' +%Y%m%d) last monday"
> ```

Comment: How about date -d 'last Monday' +%Y%m%d ?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/doing-date-math-command-line-part-ii) article, is gives a function to use things like 'last monday' from a given date.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be your desired answer as it does not use the string such as `last monday` but how about:

```
given="Mar 16"                          # example
dow=$(date -d "$given" +%w)             # day of week (0: Sun .. 6: Sat)
before=$(( (dow + 5) % 7 + 1 ))         # days to go back
date -d "$given -$before days" +%Y%m%d  # result
```